# __EFMigrationsHistory remains empty even though the database is created

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I have an issue with EF Core 6 that is the history table of migrations remains empty but when I check the sql server the db is created successfully with all the tables are created also.
I use Code-first approach so I run `Add-Migration <name>` to generate migrations.
When I run `Update-Database` I was running perfectly fine.
what I did is updating EF Core from `6.0.16` to  `6.0.21`, Added new Entity `mytablename` to my models so I
generate its migration. then I run `Update-Database` it gives me now
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database. Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16`
`mytablename` is created but `__EFMigrationsHistory` is not updated.
I tried some solutions like drop db and recreated from scratch, then I tried deleting db and all migrations and regenerate them but it did not work still same error.
thank you for helping me I am new to EF Core and DotNet products.

I tried some solutions like dropping db and recreated it from scratch, then I tried deleting db and all migrations and regenerate them but it did not work still same error.
thank you for helping me I am new to EF Core and DotNet products.
here is the first migration:

```cs
public partial class CreateIdentitySchema : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserLogins",
            columns: table => new
            {
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserTokens",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 128, nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "RoleNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            column: "NormalizedName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserClaims",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "EmailIndex",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "NormalizedEmail");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "UserNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            column: "NormalizedUserName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserLogins");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUserTokens");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

When I populate __EFMigrationsHistory manually and run `update-database` it works fine , but when I drop the db and rerun `update-database` it gives the same error.
When I run `dotnet ef migrations list`:

> 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema (Pending)
>
> 20230807142821_CreateAppDb (Pending)
>
> 20230809091829_AppTable (Pending)
>
> 20230809100343_UserPersonalData (Pending)
>
> 20230810084347_db (Pending)

> Program:

```cs
    public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //authorization to apps policies
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DelibAppAccess", policy =>
                policy.RequireClaim("AllowedToAppName"));
        });

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationService, ApplicationService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegisterService, RegisterService>();

        //identity password
        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        app.MapRazorPages();

        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var roles = new[] { "SuperAdmin", "Admin", "Member", "Guest" };
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
            }
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var apps = new[] { "AppName" };
            if (dbContext is not null)
            {
                foreach (var application in apps)
                {
                    if (!dbContext.Applications!.Where(a => a.Label.Equals(application)).Any())
                    {
                        dbContext.Applications!.Add(new Application() { Label = application });
                    }
                }
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

> DbContext

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : 
    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        try
            {
                if (Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() is RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator)
                {
                    if (!databaseCreator.CanConnect())
                    {
                        databaseCreator.CreateAsync().Wait();
                    }
                    if (!databaseCreator.HasTables())
                    {
                        databaseCreator.CreateTablesAsync().Wait();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }


    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //filtering users by isEnabled
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasQueryFilter(user => user.IsEnabled);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Application>? Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show the EF contexts that are involved. It seems you never had a migration including ASP.Net identity tables.

Comment: I edited the post with the very first migration which contains Identity tables.

Comment: `AspNetRoles` is added by ASP.NET Core Identity. I suggest starting a new clean project to check how things actually work, and taking care to add new entities and migrations one by one, testing them at every step. It's unclear what steps you took to get to this point, but the project is probably messed up by now. It would be a good idea to commit after every successful migration. This way, when you find a problem you'll be able to find out what exactly caused the problem

Comment: You'll need to start from a clean project too, so you can describe the steps needed to reproduce the problem. Right now you haven't explained what *your* code does - there's no DbContext, no custom entities. Just the out-of-the-box Identity classes.

Comment: I'll edit my question with program.cs and DbContext.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing:

```cs
try
{
  if (Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() is RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator)
  {
    if (!databaseCreator.CanConnect())
    {
      databaseCreator.CreateAsync().Wait();
    }
    if (!databaseCreator.HasTables())
    {
      databaseCreator.CreateTablesAsync().Wait();
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```